# How to style a byline field in an article content type?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

There might be a simple answer to this but it's driving me crazy. I'm working on a template for an article node and I want the byline to display this way:

> By Author Name

I don't want to change the field label in the web form, so I just want the "By" to be inserted through the node template. No matter what CSS styling I use, the byline field always displays like this:

> By
>   Author Name

Is there a way to get the label and field to show up inline?

Here's the PHP I'm using in the template:

```
<div class="newsbyline">
  <?php print t('By'); ?> <?php print render($content['field_newsbyline']); ?>
</div>
```

Setting the "newsbyline" `<div>` to inline doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: In CSS, try setting the tags surrounding  "by" and "Author Name" to float:left; and then check.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the markup that surrounds the newsbyline field. I'm guessing there's a div or some other element around `field_newsbyline` that's a block element by default. If you change the CSS for that element to `display: inline` that may solve the problem.

Alternatively, if the above code is in your node template, you could adjust the markup in the field template instead:

1. Copying `field.tpl.php` from the base theme you're using or from Drupal core's `/modules/field/theme/` into your theme
2. Rename it `field--field-newsbyline.tpl.php` (assuming field_newsbyline is the machine name of your field)
3. Edit that template to add `<?php print t('By'); ?>` in the appropriate spot.

By making the change in the field template, you should be able to get your code inside the wrapper div, rather than having it outside.